# Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError - Sequelize MYSQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am stuck with this error for close 2 days yet could not find a solution to solve this.

I am currently using `Sequelize` version `"^4.37.10"` and `mysql2` version `"^1.5.3"`. Previously it was working fine until 2 days ago I got hit with this error.

I am not connecting it to a local database but a database from heroku, so I believe the following method which I found online does not really solve my issue:

```
update user set authentication_string=password(''), plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';
```

Error log:

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionError: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client
    debuggability.js:868
        at Utils.Promise.tap.then.catch.err (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodejstest\testmysql\webapp\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connection-manager.js:149:19)
        at tryCatcher (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodejstest\testmysql\webapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodejstest\testmysql\webapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
        at Promise._settlePromise (c:\Users\User\Desktop\nodejstest\testmysql\webapp\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
```

Did I accidentally deleted some files or what ? How can I solve this ?  I have also tried removing mysql2 and sequelize modules and reinstall but still did not work. Even after deployment to Heroku, this error still exists. Appreciate your help.